# ga:productCategoryHierarchy vs ga:productCategoryLevelXX

Tags: google-analytics

I'm having trouble understanding the difference between ga:productCategoryHierarchy and ga:productCategoryLevelXX. Unfortunately [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=ecommerce&jump=ga_productcategoryhierarchy) doesn't tell much either, imho.

I'm trying to represent a product in a category taxonomy, e.g.:

```
Product A: category 1 -> category 1.1 -> category 1.1.2
Product B: category 1 -> category 1.2 -> category 1.2.1
```

I originally tried this by separating categories with a `/` in the ga:productCategoryHierarchy field, but that didn't work (i.e. showed the whole string in the GA reports, no possibility to drill down individually).

I've somewhere read that we can use ga:productCategoryLevelXX (and substitute XX with a number between 1 and 5) and pass category names like that.

Is there a best practice? What variant are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using [enhanced ecommerce](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#product-data) you send in the full product category delimited by `/`, for example: `Apparel/Men/T-Shirts`.

When using the [Core reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/) you can query for both the category hierachy `ga:productCategoryHierarchy` which would return the full string `Apperel/Men/T-shirts` or you can query for the `ga:productCategoryLevelXX`, For example querying for `ga:productCategoryLevel2` would return `Men`.